# How to stop one function using another function in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, execution

I have a function call `settrigger`, basically this is a function that will keep running until certain condition is fulfilled. However, I want to add a function which can stop the execution of the `settrigger` function manually instead of clicking `Cancel` to stop the running script. May I know how should the function look like? Appreciate your help!

This is my script:

```
function settrigger() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var y = 1;
  var z = 1

  while ( y != 100000 ){
    var x = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').getValue();
    x=x+1;
    ss.getRange('A15').setValue(x);
    y=y+1;
    var toggle = ss.getRange('A1')
    if (x%2==0){
      toggle.setBackground("RED");
    } else if (x%2!=0) {
      toggle.setBackground("WHITE");
    }
  }

}
```

### Stop Function

```
function stopfunc() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("stop", "stop");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var toggle = ss.getRange('A1')
  toggle.setBackground("WHITE")
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, from the function name of `settrigger`, if the function of `I have a function call settrigger, basically this is a function that will keep running until certain condition is fulfilled.` is run by a trigger, how about deleting the trigger using another function? But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I edited my question with my script attached, if you run the script, it will cause Cell A1 flashing, I just want to have a function to stop the flashing and change the color of cell A1 to white color again.

Comment: `throw` a error in first function after  checking a external value like A2 value or propertiesservice

Comment: Do you mean you encounter error when run the script above?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful or I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster Now, I noticed your comment. When I saw your comment, I thought that my proposed answer might have been the same with your direction.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function settrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var y = 1;
  var z = 1

  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  while (y != 100000 && p.getProperty("stop") == null){
    var x = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').getValue();
    x=x+1;
    ss.getRange('A15').setValue(x);
    y=y+1;
    var toggle = ss.getRange('A1')
    if (x%2==0){
      toggle.setBackground("RED");
    } else if (x%2!=0) {
      toggle.setBackground("WHITE");
    }
  }
  p.deleteProperty("stop");
}

// When you want to stop the function of `settrigger`, please run this.
function stopfunc() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("stop", "stop");
}
```

- In this case, after the function of `settrigger` was run, when `stopfunc` is run, the key `stop` of PropertiesService is created. By this, `y != 100000 && p.getProperty("stop") == null` is `false`. By this, the loop is stopped.

#### Reference:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

### Added:

From your additional question in your comment as follows,

> I tried to add few lines of code to change the background back to white color again but seems like it doesn't work well, sometime still remain red color, it depends on luck.

In this case, the reason for your issue is due to that the function `settrigger()` is stopped after the function `stopfunc()` was run. So, please modify the above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function settrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var y = 1;
  var z = 1

  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  while (y != 100000 && p.getProperty("stop") == null){
    var x = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').getValue();
    x=x+1;
    ss.getRange('A15').setValue(x);
    y=y+1;
    var toggle = ss.getRange('A1')
    if (x%2==0){
      toggle.setBackground("RED");
    } else if (x%2!=0) {
      toggle.setBackground("WHITE");
    }
  }
  p.deleteProperty("stop");
  ss.getRange('A1').setBackground("WHITE");  // Added
}

// When you want to stop the function of `settrigger`, please run this.
function stopfunc() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("stop", "stop");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The script works almost perfectly! I tried to add few lines of code to change the background back to white color again but seems like it doesn't work well, sometime still remain red color, it depends on luck. An y idea where I did wrong?

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `I tried to add few lines of code to change the background back to white color again but seems like it doesn't work well, sometime still remain red color, it depends on luck.`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: If you wish to see the changes in background reliably then you will have to insert SpreadsheetApp.flush() into the mix which will greatly reduce the speed of execution down to a crawl.  I personally wouldn't do something like this because it's kind of a hack.  I would replace with setInterval and clearInterval in a client side dialog

Comment: Thanks Tanaike for your additional script, it works perfectly now!